# Send Email from only one Standard Address

Tags: email, setup

Is there a way when sending an email from Salesforce to have one Company e-mail address (standard and forever) instead of current user's personal email ?

For example, when on Lead record -> Send Email, i want user not to have the choice between his address or the ord wide address.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use org-wide email addresses in this case.

> If your Salesforce org requires users to share a common email alias,
> you can define a list of organization-wide addresses for each user
> profile. When sending email from Salesforce, users with these profiles
> can select their own email address or the organization-wide email
> address for the email’s From field. Replies are delivered to the
> selected address.

Setup steps:

1. From Setup, enter Organization-Wide Addresses in the Quick Find box, then select Organization-Wide Addresses.
2. To manage organization-wide addresses, use the available options.

[More information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=orgwide_email.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way for users to be able to use only this e-mail? (Not their personal)

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios Yes check this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315566&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: As i see in the article this is for automated workflow rules. I would also like to achieve such functionality on record pages. For example, i go to a lead -> Send Email -> I don't want user to choose between his personal email address or the ord wide email address. I updated the question

Comment: That is not possible as of now but here is workaround for that. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315645&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

Comment: There is also an idea for that feature please vote for that. Linked in the above article

Comment: Rahul, thank you very much!!! I will upvote the idea.